# How to open custom Application when Clicking Print Button From Chrome In Android

Tags: android, google-chrome, pos, pax, android-print-manager

I have PAX A920 Device for printing invoice, and we have odoo POS system.
When I click print button from chrome browser it is opening default printing Service of android which not detect build in printer in Device. I want to know can I open my custom application for Triggering print function of build in printer, or is there any other option to configure or detect Default Print Service of Android

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "it is opening default printing Service of android"? to me it looks like it just opens the pdf and let you save it. As far as I know the browser does not send a "print request" since usually android devices cannot print anything.

What you could do is make your app compatible with pdfs so you can choose to open a pdf with your app which then prints it automatically

Comment: what i need, when i click on print button from browser, it open save as pdf screen, and the device in which i am opening it a build in printer pda Pax A920.
I want to print the receipt from that device when i click print button.
I know it start service for printer in android when any print call from browser, I want to implement the service so whenever print service started my custom application trigger print function.

Comment: @ShoaibAnwar the option to choose a printing service was added in andorid 8.0,  I don't have it so I can't check it, but if you do try to look in settings and see if the printer is detected. If not (or if you, like me, have an old version of android) I suggest you to make a custom pdf opener so you can show the pdf and add your custom button that starts printing